# What does "contact drivers" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have a　document like training manual for troubleshooting networking, 
and one section in it has a title "Contact Drivers".

Since this troubleshooting does not talk about device drivers at all, 
I have no idea what this means.

Comment: So what *does* it talk about? You still have way more information at this point than us, yet nonetheless are at a loss. Certainly with less information we'll be at a bigger loss still.

Comment: Below this title, there are some questions and answers about application install. Questions are like "I can't install this application", and answers are like "You can install this app on Windows but not on Mac."

Answer (score 2):

In this context, the "contact drivers" are the problems which cause (drive) someone to contact technical support for help. It's rather ugly business jargon, but not completely opaque.

Comment: I see! Though it still sounds a little odd to me, your explanation convinced me enough. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Yes, usually "business jargon" === "sounds odd" to normal people.